How to understand opencv's RotationWarper
Recently, I am doing image stitching, and I found stitching_detailed.py breaks up the steps of opencv's stitching algorithm, I read this code, have some questions about the PyRotationWarper:

What is the necessity of warping image in the pipeline of stitcinging
How to choose warp type and set scale properly when create warper instance
How to understand the input parameters K and R of the function warp()? I know they represent the camera intrinsic matrix and the rotation matrix, but I dn't know how they works here.
What is the coordinate system of the top-left corner output by the warp() function? Where is its origin, and why might it have negative values?

I google searched RotationWarper and found there are little information and example code about it, which make me still confused about it.
I feel these questions stem from my lack of SLAM knowledge, it would be nice if someone could provide some background knowledge, and preferably with example code using cv.PyRotationWarper along with visualization.

try this instead: https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching it uses OpenCV's stitching but helps you understand better

this is the PR that added this "py rotation warper". IDK if the name stems from any typos. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/13267 you might want to track down the author of the PR and ask for better docs. I think there first was a "rotation warper" for... I think 3D/spherical models (as opposed to planar models). then that person came along and created a new example in Python, and must have thought to create a new class just for that, and called it like that.

Hi @ChristophRackwitz, thanks for your comments. The key point of my question actually lies in RotationWarper. It's not about whether it's a C++ or Python binding wrapper. I mentioned PyRotationWarper just because I'm more familiar with Python and prefer example codes in Python, but C++ is also okay.

the name is an accident. it has nothing to do with Python, as far as I can tell. contact the author of the PR. nobody else will know why he called it that.

Funny enough I named the interface to pyRotationWarper in the stitching package just warper
